# How was the Mozambique Belt formed

Tags: geology, volcanic-eruption, east-africa-rift

I'm looking for some of the most comprehensive or significant articles on the Mozambique Belt in East Africa.  If anyone can recommend some specific papers regarding the Geological history of the belt I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome! Your question is super broad... Could you narrow it down a little bit? I have papers about volcanoes of the rift, it is a topic very different topic from cratons or the Mozambic belt...

Comment: [Related](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13848/has-our-understanding-of-the-east-african-rift-significantly-changed-recently?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. I would specifically like to know more about the formation of the Mozambic belt . That would be great. thanks

Comment: Then you should edit your question to reflect this focus: "How was the Mozambic belt formed?", or something like this, and remove the other parts in the body. You can of course ask about them in separate, focused questions.

Comment: You might have a bit more success if you look for Mozambique instead of Mozambic. This might be a good start, [*THE GEOLOGY OF  THE  MOZAMBIQUE BELT AND THE ZIMBABWE CRATON AROUND MANICA, WESTERN MOZAMBIQUE*](https://repository.up.ac.za/bitstream/handle/2263/28883/01chapters1-3.pdf?sequence=2)